# Django how to make select form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to make select phone service agency when user sign up. but my select form doesn't appear in the html.
is there any way to make select form?

**models.py**

```
        class User(AbstractUser):
    ...
            phone_service_provider = models.CharField(
                max_length=11, choices=AGENCY_CHOICES, blank=False
            )
    ...
```

**forms.py:**

```
    class SignUpGeneralForm(forms.Form):
...
        address_postcode_general = forms.CharField(
            widget=forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    "id": "postcode",
                    "placeholder": "우편번호",
                    "class": "appearance-none bg-transparent border-none w-full text-gray-700 mr-3 py-1 px-2 leading-tight focus:outline-none",
                    "style": "width:100%; height:100%;",
                    "readonly": "true",
                }
            )
        )
    
        phone_service_provider = forms.ChoiceField(
            widget=forms.Select(choices=AGENCY_CHOICES)
        )
    
        phone_number = forms.CharField(
            widget=forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    "placeholder": "핸드폰 번호",
                    "class": "appearance-none bg-transparent border-none w-full text-gray-700 mr-3 py-1 px-2 leading-tight focus:outline-none",
                    "style": "width:100%; height:100%;",
                }
            )
        )
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

widget in formsField is only for html attributes, the choices need to be in Field, no widgets, so :

```
   phone_service_provider = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(),
        choices=AGENCY_CHOICES
    )
```